# Haproxy doesn't go to the write backend after coming back from Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I am using haproxy and nginx to load balance as well as protect (through naxsi in nginx) my web servers. Haproxy is working fine but the minute I send it through nginx it defaults everything to the default backend instead of checking against our webmail backend. In the nginx error and access log it is showing the correct host name but still it gets sent down the default_backend bk_comweb instead of the use_backend bk_webmail. There's something I'm missing but can't see the forest through the trees, any help would be greatly appreciated!

haproxy.conf important lines:

```
frontend ft_protection
        bind 10.0.5.15:80
        mode http
        option http-server-close
        #DDOS protection
        #Use General Purpose Couter (gpc) 0 in SC1 as a global abuse counter
        #Monitors the number of request sent by an IP over a period of 10 seconds
        stick-table type ip size 1m expire 1m store gpc0,http_req_rate(10s),http_err_rate(10s)
        tcp-request connection track-sc1 src
        tcp-request connection reject if { sc1_get_gpc0 gt 0 }
        #Abuser means more than 100reqs/10s
        acl abuse sc1_http_req_rate gt 100
        acl kill sc1_inc_gpc0 gt 10
        acl save sc1_clr_gpc0 ge 0
        tcp-request connection accept if !abuse save
        tcp-request connection reject if abuse kill
        default_backend bk_protection
```

backend bk_protection
        mode http
        option http-server-close
        #If the source IP generated 10 or more http request over the defined period,
        #flag the IP as abuser on the frontend
        acl abuse sc1_http_err_rate gt 10
        acl kill sc1_inc_gpc0 gt 0
        tcp-request content reject if abuse kill
        server waf1 10.0.5.3:81 maxconn 10000 check

frontend ft_web
        bind 10.0.6.3:81
        mode http
        option http-server-close
        acl webmail hdr(host) -i newwebmail.example.com
        acl comwebmail hdr_beg(host) -i webmail
        use_backend bk_webmail if webmail or comwebmail
        default_backend bk_comweb

nginx.conf:

```
http {
 include        /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;
 include        mime.types;
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
```

sendfile        on;
 keepalive_timeout  65;
 tcp_nodelay        on;

gzip  on;
 gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

server {
 proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "";
 listen       10.0.5.3:81;

location / {
   include    /etc/nginx/test.rules;
   proxy_pass http://10.0.6.3:81/;
  }

error_page 403 /403.html;
 location = /403.html {
  root /opt/nginx/html;
  internal;
 }

location /RequestDenied {
     return 403;
   }
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I needed to add proxy_set_header Host $host; to the server section.